# How to convert a number in a text file to its hex value in c

Tags: c, assembly, hex

Im attempting to create a basic assembler in C in which i am just simply taking in instructions from an input file and then translating those instructions into machine language/hex values. I am stuck on those that take in an integer value that is either their offset or in the case of `addimmediate` the value to be added. Below is what i have so far and while it does seem to work to translate the given value to its correct hex value it doesnt produce the right output when using `od -t x1 output.txt | head -5` to see the hex values. At the moment `addimmediate R1 8` produces an output of `ef bf bd 08` which i am confused as to why that is the case when it should be `91 08`

**PR1.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ltrim(char *s) {
    while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') s++;
    return s;
}

char getRegister(char *text) {
    if (*text == 'r' || *text=='R') text++;
    return atoi(text);
}
char getHex(char *text){
    int number = (int)strtol(text, NULL, 16);
    return number;
}
int assembleLine(char *text, unsigned char* bytes) {
    text = ltrim(text);
    char *keyWord = strtok(text," ");
    if (strcmp("add",keyWord) == 0) {
        bytes[0] = 0x10;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL," "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL," ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL," "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("subtract", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x50;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("and", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x20;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("divide", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x30;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("multiply", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x40;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("or", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x60;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("halt", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x00;
        bytes[1] = 0x00;
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("return", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x70;
        bytes[1] = 0x00;
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("addimmediate", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x90;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *src = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE *dst = fopen(argv[2],"w");
    while (!feof(src)) {
        unsigned char bytes[4];
        char line[1000];
        if (NULL != fgets(line, 1000, src)) {
            printf ("read: %s\n",line);
            int byteCount = assembleLine(line,bytes);
            fwrite(bytes,byteCount,1,dst);
        }
    }
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine here. You have problem elsewhere. The `ef` stuff looks suspiciously like an utf8 bom.

Comment: I deleted the output file ive been using over and over again and just reran my program and bam just like that. Worked. what is a utf8 bom? i am unfamiliar but im assuming it was the problem?

Comment: Since you use `"w"` for `fopen` and that should truncate your output file, I am slightly puzzled though ...

Comment: ive been running it over and over again after coding each "command" to ensure that it works, could that perhaps have caused this issue? It is seemingly solved now that i have refreshed the output file but i dont quite understand why. Also for an interrupt command, would interrupt 0 produce a hex of `80 00` and would an interrupt 1 produce a hex of `81 11` or just `81 00` ?

Comment: Check if the first bytes are `ef bf bd 08 91`. Then it's a BOM problem, because `08 91` is the _little endian_ representation of `91 08`.